# Unable to Partition Drive - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ubuntu-18.04

I am unable to repartition my single Linux drive. For clarity, I have done the following:

1a) Restarted my computer on a USB/CD boot of Linux

1b) Used Gparted to unmount the drive I want to partition **(Ignore the lock in the picture below)**.

1c) Attempted to shrink the Linux partition and create a new partition (see *Resizing*)

None of the above has worked...it only allows me to create 32 mbs of "unused" disk space. I am not currently using the full 119.24 GB of my drive for Linux.

[Gparted - Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcgiA.png)

[Gparted - Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ86e.png)

Comment: Please see this: [*How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)*](https://askubuntu.com/q/196125/693277).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture it appears that ubuntu is installed in a Logical Volume Management Physical Volume (LVM2 PV), and not simply in a partition formatted with a file system. See Logical Volume Manager (Linux) for a description of LVM. Currently there is no unallocated space within the LVM2 PV and hence the LVM2 PV cannot be shrunk. You might have unused space within the Logical Volumes within the LVM2 PV.

When you installed Ubuntu, the installation have used the whole drive as 1 LVM partition, and that's why you can't create another partition, since there is no space left.

This might help

https://askubuntu.com/questions/124465/how-do-i-shrink-the-root-logical-volume-lv-on-lvm/124480#124480

Comment: Thanks. You accurately described what I did and the problem rather nicely. I decided I needed a new laptop and am going to have two laptops for separate OS projects, but I will try this out soon.